# how to reverse an anonymous list in template toolkit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

Is it possible to reverse an anonymous list in template toolkit?

e.g.

```
[% FOREACH month IN [1..12].reverse %]
    [% month %]
[% END %]
```

(except that doesn't work).

Just wondered if there was a neat way to do it without using variables or explicitly typing out the array.

Comment: Looks like someone needs to a write Template::Plugin::Autobox.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, there isn't. Being able to instantiate anonymous arrays in situ is a special case handled by the TT parser.  You can't operate on them like you can in regular Perl without the intermediate step of assigning to a named variable.

**EDIT:** You can't even pass in a subroutine to try to use like so:

```
[% FOREACH month IN my_reverse([1..12]) %]
    [% month %]
[% END %]
```

Nor can you try to use a method on an object:

```
[% FOREACH month IN testObj.my_reverse([1..12]) %]
    [% month %]
[% END %]
```

They will compile, but in each case, the `FOREACH` construct sees the head of the chain, e.g. a `CODE` reference in the first case and a blessed object in the second.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's very useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little new but what about this:

[% months = ['jan','feb','mar',...]; ## array of months

[% FOREACH i = [(months.size-1)*-1 .. 0] %]  ## counts -11 to 0 for 12 elements
[% months[(i*-1)] ## converts i to positive number - displays months[11], months[10] ... months[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- show 2010 2009 2008 2007 -->
[% SET startyear = 2007 %]
[% SET endyear = 2010 %]
[% SET allyears = [ startyear .. endyear ] %]
[% FOREACH year IN alleyears.reverse %]
   <li>[% year %]</li>
[% END %]
```